# how can we do logging of conversation messages in database in ibm watson using node.js

Tags: node.js, logging, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a watson conversation using assistant-simple github repo in node.js and it is working fine locally  and in ibm cloud also. Now I want to log these conversation messages in a database. How can I log these conversation messages using database in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assistant will keep the messages in a log for a small period of time [List logs for a workspace](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#list-log-events-in-a-workspace) and see [Log limits](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/logs.html#logs).

Alternatively you will have to code putting messages into a database inside the NodeJS (or other language) server Orchestrator layer (which the UI communicates with). This layer gets all the user messages and Assistant responses and so can store them where you want.

I am not aware of a sample which directly communicates with Assistant and stores the user messages in a database. You would need to take various pieces of code and put them together to achieve this.

For example [this sample](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/get-started-node) shows how to upload information to a Cloudant database running on IBM Cloud, using NodeJS.

Alternatively if you don't want to write the code locally, you can invoke App Connect to store the data in a database. This [Assistant and App Connect sample](https://github.com/IBM/watson-assistant-app-connect) shows how to use Assistant actions to invoke AppConnect at some point in the dialog flow, either from the Assistant service (using a Cloud Function) or from the Orchestrator layer (as a client action).

The sample passes a user Id found in the utterance, but the approach is to take some data from Assistant, invoke App Connect and pass it to App Connect, and App Connect calls some other external system with the data. In your case, the data could be the user utterance and Assistant response, and App Connect could store this in a database.

Comment: can you suggest me any sample application which used  watson conversation and logging together??

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to leverage [cloud functions](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/cloud/functions) to make a call to another service.
Depending on what you want to do with the conversation data. If you wanted to access chatlogs and metrics you could send it to a logging service such as [www.chatseer.com](https://www.chatseer.com) so you can access the logs.